# How do I create a granite / stone effect using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture, terminology

This might be weird but I want to PS the four cats...

[image]

into something like the four presidents on Mount Rushmore...

[image]

I haven't touched PS for a long time, would appreciate some hints here.

Comment: @Vincent I have tried to search for some tutorial on youtube...none of them worked. I have also tried to play with opacity, doesn't seem to work very well.

Comment: I down voted. This is essentially asking for a tutorial on demand without showing *any* effort to solve the issue in the question.

Comment: @Scott I said I haven't touched PS for a long time. Downvote as you like, but just don't make unreasonable judgement.

Comment: Whether or not you've "touched PS" is irrelevant. GD.SE is *not* a tutorial on demand site as far as I'm aware. Questions should some **some** effort. This one shows very little if any.

Comment: @Scott Haven't I said I only want some hint? How on earth can you see this as a demand for tutorial???

Comment: Show what you have tried. and why you feel it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Look up `Texture Mapping in Photoshop` and `Displacement Map Photoshop` and you'll get closer to the results you're after than trying to do it with just opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the two solutions. Anything else? I will approve this answer after a while if you don't mind.

Comment: @TroyWoo not really, that's the only way you're going to get close using Photoshop. Feel free to ask other questions if you get stuck along the way just be sure to show your work and some effort.

Comment: It does not work well so I didn't bother showing the results here. Most tut did with a much smoother human face. But in my case, the cats are just too furry...I guess it is impossible. A complete redrawing is the only way...